# location of DIV tag in DOM

Tags: html

I was validating  my moodle website with the [w3c validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).  in it, there is this code that caused a lot of problems:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en" class="yui3-js-enabled">
<div id="yui3-css-stamp" style="position: absolute !important; visibility: hidden !important" class=""></div>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Course: Program 1 :title</title>


<meta name="keywords" content="moodle, xxxxxxxxx">
<script async="" src="./test_files/analytics.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
```

my question is, can a div tag be inside a  tag, but not in a body??

Comment: why do you want an div in this location?

Comment: this is not 'my' website, it is a website i am working with.  moodle is a huge education platform.  there is a bug in it that they will look into.  it is something to do with ajax/YUI.
i noticed the error and asked the question  is it valid HTML. i didn't think it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can not - it is not proper HTML,

of course it will still work in almost any browser , as most modern browsers are very lenient with improper HTML

It looks like you have it positioned absolutely, maybe I'm assuming because you want it way up on top above anything else.  Don't worry - you can still accomplish this behavior inside the `<body>` tag

Comment: thanks i thought not, i looked for references, but was unable to find any.  never mind i will let the moodle people know.

Answer (score 1):

While HTML is a flexible and browsers are forgiving, HTML does specify a basic structure. Content in the header contains meta data about the page, as well as resources like CSS the browser should get. The part of the document tree used by the browser to paint the web page should be based on content in the body tag.

Here is a revised sample of your markup to show one way to improve it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en" class="yui3-js-enabled">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Course: Program 1 :title</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="moodle, xxxxxxxxx">
    <script async="" src="./test_files/analytics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="yui3-css-stamp" style="position: absolute !important; visibility: hidden !important" class=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but i didn't ask how to fix it, just if it was valid to have a div inside a html before head.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is No its improper way of doing it The page may or may not break depending on browser

Answer (score 0):

No, div tag must be inside body tag.